# SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.x OR t.y IN (SELECT id FROM z)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is something like this possible (I know this statement is not working, I tried it):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.x OR t.y IN (SELECT id FROM z)
```

Example

Table t:

```
|id|x  |y
|1 |101|201 
|2 |102|202
```

Table z:

```
|id  |
|101 | 
|201 |
```

And from this table t I want to select all entries where either attribute x or attribute y is contained in the list of ids of table z.

I know I can do

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.x IN (SELECT id FROM z) OR t.y IN (SELECT id FROM z)
```

but this feels like it is very inefficient when the `IN` values are coming from a complex subquery (which then is the same in both `IN` clauses).

Or are current query planner implementations clever enough to see that both subqueries give the same results and only execute this one time? Or maybe there is another solution using `EXISTS` which I currently don't see?

PS: I'm using Postgres, but I'm looking for a generic solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM z where z.id in (t.x,t.y))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `z` is a complex query, then you can use a CTE to simplify the code:

```
WITH z AS (
      . . . 
     )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE t.x IN (SELECT id FROM z) OR t.y IN (SELECT id FROM z);
```

You can also use `JOIN` or `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM z
              WHERE z.id IN (t.x, t.y)
             );
```

The `JOIN` version has the downside that rows can multiply due to duplicates in `z`.

That said, the version with the two `IN` expressions is possibly the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
SELECT t.* FROM t join z on t.x = z.id or t.y = z.id
```

Comment: This is not necessarily the same thing

Comment: This could result duplicate records if id is duplicated in `z` table

Comment: Then you can use `distinct` if necessary.